# How to programmatically send GPS location to an Android Studio 2.0 AVD

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, appium, telnet

I have an x86 API23 AVD (with Google APIs) created with Android Studio 2.1.1 that I need to send GPS coordinates to. I've read extensively on doing this using either "adb emu geo fix" commands from the command line, or via telnet-- after authenticating, and then sending geo fix commands along with the latitude, longitude, and optional altitude parameters at the command line as well.

I'm running my code on a Mac OSX El Capitan box.

The problem is that my application-- the app that needs to be fed the GPS coordinates that I'm sending, acts as if it is not getting any data.

If I use the Extended controls on the AVD itself to send the same current location with the SEND button, or PLAY out route data loaded from a .gpx file, then all works fine. The app gets the GPS data and behaves as expected.

The problem is that I am running test automation (Appium, Java, TestNG) that needs to launch the AVD, then send the GPS data, and then verify that my app under test behaved as expected when it was fed the correct GPS data.

This means that I cannot manually interact with the AVD's extended manual controls.

I must do this all, programmatically.

Here's what I'm doing now via Telnet commands. The code looks essentially like so for sending just a "Current Location":

```
import org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient;

static TelnetClient tc = null;

    public InputStream inptStream;
    public PrintStream outptStream;
    public String prompt = "OK";

//Instantiate the telnet client -- we use this to send geo fix commands to the emulator
            tc = new TelnetClient();

//Connect, this will generate the auth_token if it does not already exist in file system
                System.out.println("Trying to connect to AVD...");
                tc.connect("localhost", 5554);

//Check to see if we are connected
                Boolean areWeConn = tc.isConnected();
                System.out.println("Are we connected?" + areWeConn);

// Get input and output stream references
                System.out.println("Getting input and output streams...");
                inptStream = tc.getInputStream();
                outptStream = new PrintStream(tc.getOutputStream());

                //wait for OK prompt
                System.out.println("Waiting for the OK prompt...");
                //Not including readUntil() code because it's just reading  terminal output
                readUntil(prompt);

                //Send the auth token number
                System.out.println("Sending auth token...");
                outptStream.println("auth " + "3A/Yfazi3pRcvNiB");
                outptStream.flush();

                //wait for OK prompt
                System.out.println("Waiting for the OK prompt...");
                readUntil(prompt);

                //Send current location for our Starting Point
                System.out.println("Sending Current Location - Starting Point");
                outptStream.println("geo" + "fix" + "28.4194 -81.5812");
                outptStream.flush(); 

//Now disconnect from Telnet
                System.out.println("Disconnecting from AVD...");
                tc.disconnect();

//Check to see if we are still connected
                Boolean stillConn = tc.isConnected();
                System.out.println("Are we still connected? " + stillConn);
```

When the above code failed to trigger the expected behavior in my app, even though it appears to work without any errors at all, I used a terminal to launch the AVD with my app running on it, and then used another terminal to send the "current location" manually with the following commands (after authenticating) at the Telnet OK prompt:

```
telnet localhost 5554
```

Wait for OK...

Then authenticate manually by sending the auth token...

Wait for OK, then send:

```
geo fix "28.4194 -81.5812"
```

This command appeared to work perfectly at the prompt (no errors), but my app apparently didn't get any GPS information.

So, I tried using the adb version of the above command, which works like so:

```
adb emu geo fix "28.4194 -81.5812"
```

But this too failed to work.

Likewise, using Appium's own Android Driver I tried the following (after creating the driver, of course):

```
Location currLocation = new Location(28.41936, -81.5812, 0.0);

            //Set Current Location for
            myDriver.setLocation(currLocation);
```

But the driver appears to 'hang' here. No debug output could be gotten by me. It just... blocks, until things eventually time out.

And, I've tried all the above with the Google Maps mobile app as well, but it too fails to react to the current location coordinates that I send.

So, I am stuck!

Has anyone actually had luck with PROGRAMMATICALLY sending "geo fix" commands to their apps under test on an API23 AVD created with Android Studio 2+?

AVDs created by versions of Android Studio earlier than 2.0 cannot be used for my purposes.

Any feedback on what I'm doing wrong or possible work-arounds would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Wulf

Answer (score 2):

So, believe it or not, by sending longitude first, and then lattitude like so:

```
geo fix "-81.5812 28.4194"
```

The geo fix command worked for me!

Thus, the corrected code looks like this:

```
//Send current location for our Starting Point
                System.out.println("Sending Current Location - Starting Point");
                outptStream.println("geo fix -81.5812 28.4194");
                outptStream.flush();
```

Ugh... days to figure that out, bro. Days...

I could not get the "adb emu geo fix" commands to work in my code, so I'm using the straight "geo fix" commands above and this is perfect for setting "current location".

However, "geo fix" commands do not appear to be working for me to create a route that my app draws to a map. I have a simple array of coordinates--all corrected now to give long then lat, and I play them out in a loop--but this is not working to give me a ROUTE to follow in my app.

Any ideas on how the Extended controls in Android Studio 2.0 are sending the .gpx coordinates to the emulator so that apps read this stream of info as a ROUTE rather than a single current location, marked one by one?

I hope that made sense.

****UPDATE 6/20/2016 ****

So, the above question was ill premised. Not long after posting the above query on sending "routes" instead of "current location" I discovered that an array of locations, sent one by one with "geo fix" commands does indeed work with my app and a route gets displayed on my app's map just fine! I made two big errors. First off, I was sending the ENTIRE ARRAY at once to my loop, instead of sending one location command at a time. And two, my code was not waiting for the "OK" prompt coming back on the Telnet session after each "geo fix" command was sent before sending the next "geo fix" command. Once I got these issues corrected, then things started working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing this file: ~/.emulator_console_auth_token (or creating an empty one)

---

I am in the same situation.  However, I discovered something that may help.  In a recent release for the emulator 25.1.6, the auth command is now the required first command that must be issued when using Telnet.

http://tools.android.com/recent/emulator2516releasenotes

So to disable it you can make the ~/.emulator_console_auth_token an empty file.  This seems to fix adb usage like adb emu geo fix X Y

I suspect that adb is not issuing this auth command, and would prefer to use secure method.  So I am still researching that.

Also, I have not tried all scenarios, but I also enabled in the AVD Settings > Location > mode to High so it would allow use of Google Location Services.

The way I tested:
1.  Cleared .emulator_console_auth_token
2.  Launched emulator (API 23, x86_64 qemu)
3.  Opened Google Maps App
4.  It was zoomed out signaling that it had no location
5.  adb emu geo fix 37 -122
6.  Maps zoomed in on location.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Gilgeson, thanks for the great feedback! I will give your empty token trick a try the next chance I get! However, I used the ADB commands in my code after I had already connected with a valid auth token, and they still didn't appear to work. I could have futzed something though.

Comment: Cool I am glad you figured out both sending a position and a route!  Also thanks for the reversal of lat/long.  I will check that out, maybe it will allow me to continue using authentication.  One last thing, I notice above you are using double quotes around the lat/long for adb, but when I have gotten it to work I don't put them in double quotes just as separate values:  adb emu geo fix 28.4194 -81.5812   Let me know if that helps with adb